# User account doesn't display anything except background and cursor

Tags: unity, compiz, login, password, users

I did something in CompizConfig Manager and the launcher and other bars was gone!

- I tried using the set background from right click menu and checked if it was a driver problem, but it was not.
- I also tried keyboard shortcuts for terminal etc. but none worked.
- I switched my PC off and logged in with standard user which doesn't have a password and it worked completely.

So I went back to the account with problem (admin) and made it a standard user and the other user an admin but I forgot to set a password for the other account.

Now I can't do anything in the other account because it requires admin password and my not working admin's user password doesn't work, and the other user which I made admin doesn't have a password so I can't do anything like access hard drive to save my user files to windows partition, delete account, delete compiz etc.

Comment: Your original problem could have been solved by opening a terminal and issuing the command:

    unity --reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem could have been solved by opening a terminal and issuing the command:

```
unity --reset
```

It's likely that your easiest course of action at this point is to:

Boot from live installation media (CD/DVD/USB) 
Select "Try Ubuntu without making changes to your computer"

Mount the drive that contains your user files, back them up by copying them to the aforementioned windows partition or other available media as desired.

Reinstall.

In future, I highly recommend backing up regularly and prior to making any changes to your system.

Comment: I deleted the not working account..and tried installing an account in the same name, but it also has the same problem...Will unity --reset do?

Comment: @user274586  All unity --reset will do is repair the problem "I did something in CompizConfig Manager and the launcher and other bars was gone!" If that's the only problem currently it will work. However, we appear to be past that point. The account changes you made cannot be resolved with that approach. If you still can't access your files from either account you'll need to proceed as outlined above

Comment: I changed the password for my working user account and made it admin. Then I tried unity --reset but it says ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated

Comment: I can't open the terminal with keyboard shortcuts from my not working user. But i can open nautilus, software center, chrome by creating a document and opening with respected apps. Do you have a way to open terminal alternatively?

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the problem. I somehow deleted unity. Reinstalled unity and used setsid unity to fix!

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't answer the original question