# Just Installed Ubuntu 16.04, Showing Flashing Background and Cursor Only (No Launcher or Menubar)

Tags: unity, nvidia, 16.04, launcher

I just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04, and all I am seeing is a background and a cursor (see video below).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68N7ro254lc

I've followed all instructions at the following answer links:
[Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load)
[Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login/481620#481620)
[User account doesn't display anything except background and cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455868/user-account-doesnt-display-anything-except-background-and-cursor)

I think it has to do with my graphics card (ASUS Asus Strix STRIX-GTX980-DC2OC-4GD5 GeForce GTX 980) and Unity not loading properly, but I'm at my wit's end. Any suggestions? :(